# C# SQLite file import prevent duplicates

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am attempting to get a directory (which is ever-growing) full of .txt comma delimited files to import into my SQLite db. I now have all of the files importing ok, however I need to have some way of excluding the files that have been previously added to db. I have a column in the db called FileName where the name and extension are stored next to each record from each file. Now I need to say 'If the code finds XXX.txt and XXX.txt is already in db, then skip this file'. Can I somehow add this logic to the getfiles command or is there another easy way?

```
using (SQLiteCommand insertCommand = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    SQLiteCommand cmdd = con.CreateCommand();
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\js91162\Desktop\", "R303717*.txt*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {

                        string FileNameExt1 = Path.GetFileName(file);



                        cmdd.CommandText =
                            @" 
                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Import WHERE FileName = @FileExt;";
                        cmdd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FileExt", FileNameExt1));

                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmdd.ExecuteScalar());
                    //int count = ((IConvertible)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToInt32(null));

                    if (count == 0)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Parsing CMM data for SQL database... Please wait.");

                        insertCommand.CommandText =
                            @" 
                    INSERT INTO Import  (FeatType, FeatName, Value, Actual, Nominal, Dev, TolMin, TolPlus, OutOfTol, PartNumber, CMMNumber, Date, FileName) 
                    VALUES     (@FeatType, @FeatName, @Value, @Actual, @Nominal, @Dev, @TolMin, @TolPlus, @OutOfTol, @PartNumber, @CMMNumber, @Date, @FileName);";

                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FeatType", DbType.String));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FeatName", DbType.String));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Value", DbType.String));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Actual", DbType.Decimal));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Nominal", DbType.Decimal));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Dev", DbType.Decimal));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@TolMin", DbType.Decimal));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@TolPlus", DbType.Decimal));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@OutOfTol", DbType.Decimal));
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Comment", DbType.String));




                        string FileNameExt = Path.GetFileName(file);
                        string RNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

                        string RNumberE = RNumber.Split('_')[0];

                        string RNumberD = RNumber.Split('_')[1];
                        string RNumberDate = RNumber.Split('_')[2];

                        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(RNumberDate, "yyyyMMdd", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
                        string cmmDate = dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                        bool parse = false;

                        foreach (string tmpLine in lines)
                        {


                            string line = tmpLine.Trim();
                            if (!parse && line.StartsWith("Feat. Type,"))
                            {
                                parse = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (!parse || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine(tmpLine);
                            foreach (SQLiteParameter parameter in insertCommand.Parameters)
                            {
                                parameter.Value = null;
                            }

                            string[] values = line.Split(new[] { ',' });

                            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
                            {
                                SQLiteParameter param = insertCommand.Parameters[i];
                                if (param.DbType == DbType.Decimal)
                                {
                                    decimal value;
                                    param.Value = decimal.TryParse(values[i], out value) ? value : 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    param.Value = values[i];
                                }
                            }
                            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@PartNumber", RNumberE));
                            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@CMMNumber", RNumberD));
                            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Date", cmmDate));
                            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FileName", FileNameExt));
                            // 
                            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }


                    } 
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("CMM data successfully imported to SQL database...");
                } 
                con.Close(); 
            }
```

EDIT . Perhaps if there is  a way to say   if (file 'is present in db') {  }  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the filenames from the database into a list of string, and then you use the `Except` extension method to exclude those files from the filenames returned from your directory.

```
foreach (string file in directoryFilenames.Except(databaseFilenames))
{
   // do something
}
```

Ben Robinson offers a similar answer, but using `Where` and `Contains` is going to iterate over the second list for each item in the first list. The `Except` method will only iterate over the second list once.

Comment: This is interesting.. How do you query an sqlite db to return all unique values of a given column (ex.  all the different filenames from column filename)? if i know this, i will try to create a list string and use the Except idea.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: select distinct fieldname from tablename

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply move the files toanother folder once you have processed them.

**Edit:** Your updated code will do the trick but it will take longer and longer to run as your directory fills up because you are querying the database for every file in the directory.  If you could retrive the list of imported files from the database into a `List<string>` you could then do the following using linq:

```
List<string> ImportedFiles = GetImportedFileList() // Method that gets the list of files from the db
foreach (string file in files.Where(fl => !ImportedFiles.Contains(fl)))
```

This would mean your foreach loop would only iterate through files that were not in the database already.

I have assumed you know how to write a method `GetImportedFileList()` that gets the list of files from the db and returns them as a `List<string>`.

Comment: Thats the kicker.. They are used by many people for various reasons. The location needs to remain the same. I just need to say, "ok, this has been added, now skip it and continue to the next file"

Comment: Use FileSystemWatcher to post events whenever a file is added to get around the "longer and longer" part.

Comment: Ok, I have the method as a public static void (???) setup, foreach is in place, but I am getting the following error... 

The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a reference?).

AND

'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension menthod 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could not be found.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type void to List<string>

Answer (score 0):

Make the filename column unique or add a unique index for it, and then do an INSERT OR IGNORE, causing duplicates to be ignored without throwing exceptions.